# How can you disable anaconda's 'frozen solve' feature?

Tags: anaconda

I've literally never seen anaconda's initial 'frozen solve' attempt work for installing a package. I was wondering is it possible to pass a CLI arg to disable this so that the installation process is faster?

An 'example' I'm sure we've all seen:

```
$ conda install any_package
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is currently no such CLI option.

However, if your concern is time spent solving, then you should be using Mamba.

Comment: Hello thanks! Do you know how mamba's speed compares to Conda with strict channel priority? Apparently that also speeds up anaconda.

https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-channels.html

Comment: Mamba is strictly faster in all configurations because it's a compiled SAT solver instead Python.